# tmux interactive session in new tab in Iterm2

Tags: macos, tmux, iterm2

I create new sessions like 
`tmux -CC new-session -s NAME`.
**Problem is** that new session is opened in a new window, so the are 2 iterm2 windows. I want the session to be opened in a new tab *in the same window*.

Some sessions on some remote machines are open in a new tab(not window) just like i want, but i can't control it

Comment: iterm2 has tmux integration by default. If you turn this off, a new session should appear in-window. Otherwise, use iterm2, not raw tmux commands, to configure your windows.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found a setting, which does this.
Just go to **Preferences** and switch this option marked on the screenshot:
[image]

Comment: This looks a little different in version 3.4.8. Preferences -> General -> tmux -> "When attaching, restore windows as: Tabs in the attaching window".